# Twilio call "answered" event

Tags: twilio

I use the Twilio C#/.NET helper library.

In the code below I Initiate a call through the TwilioRestClient:

```
var options = new CallOptions
{
    To = phoneNumber,
    From = fromNumber,
    Url = url,
    Method = "GET",
    FallbackMethod = "GET",
    StatusCallback = statusCallbackUrl,
    StatusCallbackMethod = "POST",
    StatusCallbackEvents = new string[] { "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" }
};

twilioClient.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
```

Сan I expect that the StatusCallback will be called with the "answered" event before Twilio makes a request to the Url address when the client (phoneNumber) picks up the phone? Or these methods are called in parallel by Twilio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`StatusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter) will be called asynchronously, so in effect the "answered" event will happen in parallel to the request to the URL you have sent as the `Url` parameter. Status callbacks are outside of the main call flow and you can't directly interact with the call by returning TwiML, they are more for storing information about the call or doing other jobs outside of the call flow itself.